# How to space geom_bar evenly when time series data is monthly

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe `df` of dates and weights (`dput` statement below), where the dates are the last business day of the month:

```
   date    factor    weight
---------------------------
2011-12-30 Margin   0.1833979
2011-12-30    ROE   0.4116400
2012-01-31 Margin   0.1268960
2012-01-31    ROE   0.5407965
2012-02-29 Margin   0.1203718
2012-02-29    ROE   0.5175672
...
```

When I try to do a bar chart, the spaces between the bars is uneven and looks bad:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = weight, fill = factor)) + geom_col(colour = "black")
```

[image: my chart]

What is the easiest `ggplot2` way of making the bars' distribution look uniform?

My `dput` statement:

```
df = structure(list(date = structure(c(15338, 15338, 15370, 15370, 15399, 15399, 15429, 15429, 15460, 15460, 15491, 15491, 15520, 15520, 15552, 15552, 15583, 15583, 15611, 15611, 15644, 15644, 15674, 15674), class = "Date"), 
  factor = c("Margin", "ROE", "Margin", "ROE", "Margin", "ROE", "Margin", "ROE", "Margin", "ROE", "Margin", "ROE", "Margin", "ROE", "Margin", "ROE", "Margin", "ROE", "Margin", "ROE", "Margin", "ROE", "Margin", "ROE"), 
  weight = c(0.183397892362647, 0.411640022340554, 0.126896048517931, 0.540796526250458, 0.120371806492843, 0.517567227285325, 0.12565548480002, 0.468107694641952, 0.128735747553961, 0.491574638977635, 0.307725896135512, 0.310517566155656, 0.340289734678739, 0.294489504073278, 0.294029009420599, 0.343346263176468, 0.311122787549636, 0.289283606959861, 0.252528512248826, 0.343976191871968, 0.325326565998995, 0.403795335070129, 0.331246359784484, 0.429392163631535)), 
  class = "data.frame", 
  .Names = c("date", "factor", "weight"), row.names = c(NA, -24L))
```

Comment: You can do better by rounding days to the first of the month, e.g. `x = as.Date(format(date, '%Y-%m-01'))`, but it's still not really right.

Comment: @alistaire.  That would get rid of some of the worst ones (where I presume the last calendar day of a short month falls on a Sunday), but it would still look funny every February/March.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could convert all of the date values to a month-year factor. For example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# Add month-year factor variable based on date
df = df %>% mutate(month = paste(month(date, label=TRUE), year(date)),
                   month = factor(month, levels=unique(month)))

# Label every third month
labs = unique(as.character(df$month))
labs[grep(paste(month.abb[-seq(1,12,3)], collapse="|"), labs)] = ""

ggplot(df, aes(x = month, y = weight, fill=factor)) + 
  geom_col(colour = "black") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=labs) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works on my toy example.  My actual data has multiple data points at each date (I'm trying to make a stacked bar chart), so this fails when I apply it to the real world.  I'll accept your answer in the absence of others because, technically, you've answered correctly.

Comment: Instead of accepting my answer, edit your question to capture the important features of your real-world problem and I'll try to update my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I've updated my answer to create a stacked bar plot.

Comment: Thanks, but I've actually posted the different question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48159994/how-to-space-geom-bar-stacked-bar-chart-evenly-when-time-series-data-is-monthly

Comment: Changing the question after it's been answered doesn't feel like in keeping with the spirit of stackoverflow.  Maybe roll your edit back, then answer the other question separately?  Or am I being too pedantic?

Comment: You should delete the other question and then update this one (although I think my updated answer covers the multiple-dates-per-month case).

Comment: Done.  Thank you.